# Restful API design: How to lock records on GET collection?

Tags: rest, api, hateoas, api-platform.com

**The idea**

Using the [API platform's](https://api-platform.com/) framework I have a case where I need to "lock access/view" to a collections of resources for the first client that requested them preventing them from being again retrieved by other client (a race condition) until the first one finishes/updates their status. 
Why: because two clients cannot process (email to a customer for example) the same coupon since coupons can be used only 1 time.

**Example**

Imagine we have a collection of coupon codes consumed by many clients: Once a collection of coupon codes is requested by a client, no other client can retrieve the same coupon codes until the first client tags (POST/PATCH) each coupon code with "consumed" for example.

**The challenge**

Of course I can lock those coupons on the GET request but this is against Restful API paradigm: a GET cannot modify the resource state, Get is supposed to be idempotent and safe.

**Suggestions**

*ETag optimistic locking*: Cannot use this on collections.

Comment: WebDAV, which, according to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), is part of the HTTP standard, provides a dedicated [locking section](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918#section-6) in its specification.

Comment: But this is regarding single resource: not collection of resources or am I wrong?

Comment: Point 4 of the lock model states: `For a collection that is locked with a depth-infinity lock L, all member resources are indirectly locked.` In the end it turns down to implementation detail I guess